# Assigning html form input a JS variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to take user form input and display it back to the user, among other things (all of which require the input being stored as a JS variable).

I'm trying to spit it out in an alert, as a quick feedback loop, and all I keep getting is [object HTMLInputElement]. I've tried to use document.forms[0] and document.getElementById (like below) and neither work. Also, I'm using bootstrap typeahead, could that be complicating this issue?

What am I missing?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="hero-unit">
    <h1> Title </h1>
    <p> This form description </p>  
    <form class="well" name="formInput" action= "#">
        <label>Input</label>
        <input Id="txtvarInput" class="span3" style="margin: 0pt auto;" type="text" placeholder="AAA, BBB, CCC..." data-provide="typeahead" data-items="10" data-source="[&quot;AAA&quot;,&quot;BBB&quot;,&quot;CCC&quot;,&quot;DDD&quot;,&quot;EEE&quot;,&quot;FFF&quot;,&quot;GGG&quot;,&quot;HHH&quot;,&quot;III&quot;,&quot;JJJ&quot;,&quot;KKK&quot;,&quot;LLL&quot;]"/>               
        </label>
        <div class="form-actions" "span3">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Select" onclick="alert('you chose ' + theInput.value)"/>
            <script language="JavaScript" type="Text/JavaScript">
                var theInput = document.getElementById('txtvarInput');
            </script>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Input:
        <script language="JavaScript" type="Text/JavaScript">
            document.write(theInput.value);
        </script>
    </h1>
```

Edit: PART II, now the code works for the alert, but I need to use it elsewhere (like I said) and the variable isn't available in other sections of the html. Above, I'm just trying to get it to display that same value as a part of the html. It could be my JS, but this is pretty boilerplate stuff, so I think it's related to the location of the variable.

What do I need to do use it elsewhere? I've added the next div above to show what I'm trying.

--left an extra declaration of the variable in part II by accident, was one of the tests I was trying, removed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, the object you're `alert`ing is an HTML element, not a string. You can get its value using the `value` property:

```
alert('you chose ' + theInput.value)
```

---

(Note that you probably *didn't* mean:

```
var theInput = document.getElementById('txtvarInput').value;
```

As other answers suggest, because that would give you an empty string. It's only read once.)

Comment: Thanks man, works like a charm. Everyone else was right that I was missing the '.value' just had me putting it in the wrong place.

Comment: now, I'm having trouble using that variable in other parts of my html. what do I need to do differently to allow the variable to be used elsewhere (in other <div>)?

Comment: @ssikes: It's global, you should be able to use it everywhere. Can you show your code, please?

Comment: @ssikes: You'll need to add the element dynamically afterwards. Look up how to do DOM manipulations with JavaScript, or ask another question.

Comment: no luck so far, if you know of a good (relevant) resource to point me to, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @ssikes: This is a good tutorial: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics (Sorry for the late reply.)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to output the entire HTML-object that you have selected, not the value-property of it. Since `alert()` expect a string, JavaScript gives you the string representation of that object which is `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

Try this instead:

```
var theInput = document.getElementById('txtvarInput').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var theInput = document.getElementById('txtvarInput');
```

should be

```
var theInput = document.getElementById('txtvarInput').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the alert, use

```
theInput.value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `value` property:

```
  var theInput = document.getElementById('txtvarInput').value;
```

Comment: Tried that before and it returns a blank, any idea why it's doing that?

Comment: Because the value is empty '' ? i.e. nothing in your text box?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot **.value**

Something like:

```
   document.getElementById('txtvarInput').value
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to print the value of the input at the page load time. You will get an empty alert.

just do this!

```
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Select" onclick="alertVal()"/>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="Text/JavaScript">
function alertVal(){
        var theInput = document.getElementById('txtvarInput').value;
        alert('you chose ' + theInput);

}
    </script>
```